# Posting to Google+ Using Apps Scripts

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps-script, google-plus

I am trying to create an apps script that will post onto Google+.

[From here:](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/plus-domains#sample_code)

```
function createPost() {
  var userId = 'me';
  var post = {
    object: {
      originalContent : 'Happy Monday! #caseofthemondays'
    },
    access: {
      items: [{
        type: 'domain'
      }],
      domainRestricted: true
    }
  };

  post = PlusDomains.Activities.insert(post, userId);
  Logger.log('Post created with URL: %s', post.url);
}
```

But I get an error:
Forbidden (line 15, file "Code")

Linke 15 is "post = PlusDomains.Activities.insert(post, userId);"

I have already authorized the g+ domain from the script and from the developers console.

Comment: It works. Also has to be turned on from within Resources >> Advanced Google Services in the script editor. You're trying it from a domain email though, right?

Comment: I am using a gmail account (ex username@gmail.com)

Comment: I get the same error. How to resolve this?